# Magento 1.9 Item Count not displaying

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart

Having problems displaying Item count in top cart (Safari).

1. Chrome: 
   [image]
2. Safari: 
   [image]

Code: 
[image]

Comment: can you share link ?

Comment: May be it's a CSS Problem Update your link in this post

Comment: @Kothari indeed it was a css issue, thanks man!